# EXC_BAD_ACESS code 1

Tags: objective-c, exception, cocos2d-iphone

I am making a app where when you touch an object, it moves. After it moves, it gets deallocated. After over thirty movements, an exception is thrown with the name EXC_BAD_ACESS with CODE = 1. Why is the exception being thrown?

```
 if (myselunit!=nil) {
                touch = [touches anyObject];
                location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
                location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];  // Locks on to touch's coordinates
                realx = location.x;
                realy = location.y;
                realDest = ccp(location.x, location.y);
                int offRealX = realx - myselunit.position.x;  // exception occurs here
                int offRealY = realy - myselunit.position.y;
                float length = sqrtf((offRealX*offRealX)+(offRealY*offRealY));
                float velocity = 50*myselunit.speed; // 480pixels/1sec
                float realMoveDuration = length/velocity;
                [myselunit runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:realMoveDuration position:realDest],[CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)],nil]];

               //             [myselunit runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(staminaUse:)],nil]];

                NSLog(@"%f",location.x);
                myselunit = nil;

            }
```

This is the backflow
Error list for myselunt:

Backflow:

- thread 1
  0x1fa509f:  movl   (%edi), %esi
  if (myselunit!=nil && myselunit.unitType != 0) {
  0x19f9e99:  addl   $28, %esp
  [handler.delegate performSelector:helper.touchesSel withObject:mutableTouches withObject:event]; [CCTouchDispatcher touches:withEvent:withTouchType:]     1
  [self touches:touches withEvent:event withTouchType:kCCTouchBegan];                                    4 -[CCTouchDispatcher touchesBegan:withEvent:]              1
  [touchDelegate_ touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];                                                 5 - [EAGLView touchesBegan:withEvent:]                      1
  0x8562cf:  movl   6769896(%esi), %eax                                                                  6 - [UIWindow_sendTouchesForEvent:]                         1
  0x82e626:  xorl   %eax, %eax                                                                           18 UIApplicationMain                                        1
  int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");                                       19 main // (memory error)                                   1
  0x2815:  movl   %eax, (%esp)                                                                           20 Start                                                    0
- thread 3
  0x9062690a:  jae    0x9062691a               ; kevent + 26                                            0 kevent                                                     1
  libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_thread:                                                               2_dispatch_mgr_thread                                        1

  - thread 6
    0x9062583e:  jae    0x9062584e               ; __psynch_cvwait + 26                                   0_psynch_cvwait                                              1
    0x97a76ed9:  movl   %ebx, %ecx                                                                        4_pthread_start                                              1

Comment: You should most code. Where is instanciate/deallocate the myselunit?

Comment: Debugging 101: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/10/xcode-4-debugging-crashcourse/ and http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 0):

**If you have a crash, post the backtrace.**

**If you know the line of the crash and that line contains variables, show how the variables are initialized.**

Given that you are later treating `myselunit` as an object, it is most likely because `myselunit` has been improperly initialized, released prior to this block of code, or otherwise mismanaged.

---

Your comments would be better as edits to the question;  more opportunity for formatting.

- it looks like you are likely managing `myselunit`'s memory incorrectly, assuming non-ARC code.
- note that your "deallocation" code doesn't appear to actually set `myselunit` to `nil`, thus leading to a dangling pointer.

Comment: I deallocate in this fashion

`            [self removeChild:unit.mylabel cleanup:YES];
            [rightUnits removeObject:unit];
            [self removeChild:unit cleanup:YES];
            unit = nil; `
The function runs after this block of code

Comment: It is initialized as such
'
                if (CGRectIntersectsRect(touchRect, targetRect)) {
                    MilitaryUnits *unitclick = (MilitaryUnits *)target;
                    myselunit=unitclick;`

Comment: I do set myselunit to nil in another part of the code, and I do use ARC code.

Comment: Then show the definition of `myselunit` and the backtrace of the crash